# single sign on coldfusion and .net

Tags: asp.net, coldfusion, single-sign-on

I have seen resources for setting up single sign on with multiple .net apps in different scenarios, but is it possible to have a SSO solution for .NET and CF websites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we use CAS. This allows a SSO solution for any development environment that our group works on as well as any other group at the University.

http://www.jasig.org/cas

The site is well documented with sample code in many different environments including .NET (http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/CASC/ASP.NET+Forms+Authentication) and Coldfusion (http://www.ja-sig.org/wiki/display/CASC/ColdFusion+client+script).

Answer (score 1):

Single Sign On is just the idea that you have one set of user credentials that all websites or intranet sites (within the SSO grouping) accept to log you in. In some cases, having a cookie from one may even automatically sign you into another.

You can build a Single Sign On solution with hundreds of different back-ends. But in its most simple form, you might try building a set of web-services that interface with your authentication data, and report back login success/failure to the application consuming the service.

Alternatively, a lot of languages, including .Net and ColdFusion support LDAP authentication, so you could just as easily use a Windows Domain (which would also open the door for Active Directory...) and LDAP authentication, so that the SSO includes the employee's workstation as well.